# Swift4 - I can not show the CollectionView the first time "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am creating an app with Swift 4, where I make a request to the API and I want to return a result on a CollectionView.

But I get the following error, which I think is from constraints:

[image]

This block is repeated 100 times.

And the result is that he does not paint any cells. Showing an image like this:

[image]

Unless I press the top button "CHANGE AUTOLAYOUT" twice. Which is when you paint the cells of the two display modes you have, and it looks like this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

But the problem is, initially nothing is shown and should be shown. And the error that I show you in the beginning appears.

To help you a little, because I would say that the problem derives from the constrainst applied, I attach some images with the different constrainsts applied.

The initial xib, where the collectionView is, are:

[image]

The cell that is initially loaded is:

[image]

The cell once we have changed the layout is this:

[image]

I attached the code of the main class, the ViewVontroller that controls the CollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

final class SpeedRunListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet private var buttonChangeLayout: UIButton!

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
private var viewModelList: SpeedRunListViewModel?
private var numElementsByCol: CGFloat = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    setupCollectionView()
    viewModelList = SpeedRunListViewModel(interactor: InteractorSpeedRunSearch())
    setupRx(viewModel: viewModelList!)
    viewModelList?.fetch()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}


private func setupCollectionView() {
    registerCollectionCells()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    calculateLayoutCollectionItem()
}


private func registerCollectionCells() {
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: SpeedRunRowCollectionViewCell.nibName, bundle: nil),
                            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SpeedRunRowCollectionViewCell.reuseCellId)

    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: SpeedRunCollectionViewCell.nibName, bundle: nil),
                            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SpeedRunCollectionViewCell.reuseCellId)

}

private func calculateLayoutCollectionItem() {
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize.init(width: 2, height: 2)
    }
}

private func setupRx(viewModel: SpeedRunListViewModel) {
    viewModel.numElements.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { e in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }, onError: { error in

    }, onCompleted: {

    }, onDisposed: {

    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)


    buttonChangeLayout.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { void in
        guard let value = self.viewModelList?.layoutRow else {
            return
        }
        self.viewModelList?.layoutRow = !value
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }, onError: { error in

    }, onCompleted: {

    }, onDisposed: {

    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

}

fileprivate func getCellId() -> String {
    if let layoutRow = self.viewModelList?.layoutRow, layoutRow == true {
        return SpeedRunRowCollectionViewCell.reuseCellId
    }
    return SpeedRunCollectionViewCell.reuseCellId
}

}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
extension SpeedRunListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let numElements = viewModelList?.numElements else {
        return 0
    }
    return numElements.value
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: getCellId(), for: indexPath) as! SpeedRunCollectionViewCellBase
    if let cellViewModel = viewModelList?.getCellViewModel(index: indexPath.row) {
        cell.setupCell(viewModel: cellViewModel)
    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let speedRun = viewModelList?.getSpeedRun(index: indexPath.row) else {
        return
    }

    let interactorDetail: InteractorSpeedRunDetail = InteractorSpeedRunDetail(speedRun: speedRun)
    let viewControllerDetail: SpeedRunDetailViewController = SpeedRunDetailViewController(interactor: interactorDetail)
    viewControllerDetail.URISpeedRunDetail = (speedRun.links![1].uri)!

    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerDetail, animated: true)
}


}
```

And the truth is that I do not know why that conflict of layouts occurs. But it's driving me crazy ... I can not understand how the cells are not shown initially (because data is being received). What could it be?

Thank you very much, any question you attach it to me.

[CODE UPDATED]

These is the code solution:

```
//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension SpeedRunListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{


    if let value = self.viewModelList?.layoutRow {
        if value {
            return CGSize(width: 320, height: 144)
        }
        else{
            return CGSize(width: 96, height: 162)
        }
    }

    return CGSize(width: 320, height: 144)

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in the viewController. You need to set it and then use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

To set the sizes of your cells.

You are having the error because when you load the cells the very first time you are basically telling them that they have a size of 0 0.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @GaloTorresSevilla
This solve my problem :) ! 
I have updated my code.